# Not a function when moved to a different file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js, typeerror

I have this coffeescript function:

```
_skip_version = (currentVersion, skippedVersions) ->
  if (currentVersion.indexOf(skippedVersions) == -1)
    return false
  return true
```

It's currently in my `archive.spec.coffee` file and works by calling like so:

```
if (_skip_version(config.version, version))
    this.skip 'Skipping test - Not supported on this version'
```

I now want other files to use `_skip_version` so `archive.spec.coffee` no longer seems to be the place to keep it. I'd like to move it to `helpers.coffee`. I copied the function to the new file and added `helpers = require('./helpers')` to `archive.spec.coffee`. Now I'm trying to call it like this:

```
if (helpers._skip_version(s3.config.clevOsVersion, version))
  this.skip 'Skipping test - Not supported on this version'
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: helpers._skip_version is not a function
```

What have I done wrong?

Here is my `hooks.coffee` file:

```
AWS = null
global = null

if typeof window == 'undefined'
   AWS = require 'aws-sdk'
   global = GLOBAL
else
   AWS = window.AWS
   global = window

if global.jasmine
   global.jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000

require('util').print = (data) ->
   process.stdout.write(data)

global.expect = require('chai').expect

matchXML = (xml1, xml2) ->
   results = []
   parser = new (require('xml2js').Parser)()
   [xml1, xml2].forEach (xml) ->
      parser.parseString xml, (e, r) ->
         if e then throw e
         results.push(r)
   expect(results[0]).to.eql(results[1])

getUniqueName = ->
  'aws-' + Date.now()

_skip_version = (currentVersion, skippedVersions) ->
   if (currentVersion.indexOf(skippedVersions) == -1)
     return false
   return true

module.exports =
   AWS: AWS
   util: AWS.util
   getUniqueName: getUniqueName
   matchXML: matchXML
```

Comment: Please share helpers.coffee file code

Comment: maybe you forgot to export it from your helper.

Comment: hooks.coffee has been added to question

Comment: That was it. Too early in the morning for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting

Change

```
module.exports =
 AWS: AWS
 util: AWS.util
 getUniqueName: getUniqueName
 matchXML: matchXML
```

To

```
module.exports =
  AWS: AWS
  util: AWS.util
  getUniqueName: getUniqueName
  matchXML: matchXML
  _skip_version: _skip_version
```